# JavaScript how to validate values that are changed by someone in console

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm building quiz type of application using PHP, MySQL and JavaScript. The thing is that there's a timer in JavaScript and one variable that stores the maximum number of minutes that the quiz will be available. Probably the easiest way to change that variable value is to open up the console in browser and re-assign new value, I tried to hide variables from direct access using immediately invoked function, but anyway it would be still possible to change that value in other ways. What should I do to properly handle this situation?

What I want to do is to make sure that user that takes the quiz can no longer see that quiz if specified time for timer ends. I just need a logic of how to properly handle it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not possible. Consider that they can just take a screenshot of the quiz before your script hides it. The best you can do is limit the ability for quiz-takers to submit the quiz. This can be done in PHP by checking the elapsed server time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not afraid of what quiz-takers can see or can take. I just wanna make sure that if time ends quiz takers couldn't select select answers but they could submit the quiz and see what they got solved in time that was specified.

Comment: You could try adding `setInterval(function(){ maxTime=whatever; }, 1000);` to continually reset the value of your max-time variable. That way if they do try to assign a new value it will just revert back every second.